# fgets not working in C linux

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I always feel lots of problem while taking char or string inputs in C linux. And see this prog. It's not taking input from the user.  Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *buf;
    int msglen;
    printf("\nEnter message length\t");
    scanf("%d",&msglen);       

    buf=malloc(msglen);

    //memset(buf,'\0',msglen+1);
    printf("\nEnter data\t");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(buf,msglen,stdin); //NOT WORKING

    fputs(buf,stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: We don't know what "not working" means.

Comment: it prints enter data and then shows prompt. not allowing user to enter anything. Just terminates the program

Comment: Did you try pressing Enter?

Comment: It's showing shell prompt ie $ , allowing to enter other commands but not any input

Comment: Does the prompt appear on the very next line?

Comment: yes. Its showing just on the next line of "Enter data"

Comment: `Any good and brief documentation on these concepts.` Have you tried searching for this? There have got to be at least a dozen decent tutorials on how to deal with this

Comment: gcc abc.c 
./a.out
This is how I am executing it.

Comment: thanks @TimCastelijns but I still could not get answer to my query above.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` causes undefined behaviour. Remove that and try again.

Comment: @MattMcNabb not working still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getchar()` instead of `fflush()`, it works.

Answer (score 2):

`fflush()` is used to flush the `output streams` and not clear the remaining characters from `stdin`. use `gets()` or `getchar()` first to remove the `EOF` from `stdin`

Comment: you cannot "remove EOF" from an input stream. Did you mean remove newline?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the integer with `scanf("%d"....)`, it does not remove the newline from the input stream. So when you call `fgets` later, it reads and finds a newline , i.e. you read a blank line.

To read the next line instead you will need to consume that newline, e.g. `getchar()` as someone else suggested.

This sort of issue is common when you mix formatted I/O (`scanf`) with unformatted I/O.